# How can I “Link to the Content” for teaser view mode of custom content type module?

Tags: nodes, 8, entities

I've created a module that's add a content type to my site and I now want to understand how can I Link a **Plain text** fields to the Content in Teaser view mode programmatically in my module?
I currently can Link to the Content any Plain text field in:

> Home>Administration>Structure>Content types>Content types name>Manage
> display

Teaser Manage display page, see below image:
[image]
and I want to understand how can I get access or implement this property (feature) in my module, I try to achieve this by adding below code to my module:

```
#core.entity_view_display.node.teaser
field_version:
  type: string
  weight: 2
  label: inline
  settings:
  third_party_settings: {  }
```

To no avail.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I can't understand the difference between what you say you can do and what you want to do.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks for your reply,  I want to implement this property in my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the setting `link_to_entity: true`:

```
field_version:
  type: string
  weight: 2
  label: inline
  settings:
    link_to_entity: true
  third_party_settings: {  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Is it possible to edit Title of content type and add this property to it, (Link Title of node Teaser to content).

Comment: The title field is not configurable. The linked title for teasers is hard coded in the node twig. It is in the variable `{{ label }}`.